# Plesk: outgoing email in spams folder

Tags: email, dns, plesk

I have a problem with my outgoing emails: they all are redirect into spam folder.
I have done a lot of things to fix this issue, but I still have the problem...

I think my DNS settings are OK. I have configured SPF like this : ***v=spf1 a mx ip4:X.X.X.X ~all***
And when I test my DNS settings on different websites (such as MxToolbox, Testdns, mail-tester and others), everything seems to be alright. You will find my DNS settings below

I really need some help, I've been trying to fix this for 3 weeks :(

Thanks
Geoffrey

Comment: This is not a programming question and thus not appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give much information, anything I (or anyone else trying to help) say is just a wild guess of what the issue could be.

Anyway, I would say that you are having issues due to misconfigured or missing reverse DNS (RDNS) record.

I am not sure what you tested, however try out [this page of MXToolBox](https://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx) and put in the hostname of your server.

In addition you should check what your log files say, they are located in `/var/log` if you are using Linux - one you are interested in is `/var/log/maillog`.

If this doesn't help, please provide additional information about your system.